# Why should I not put content in the development environment?

Tags: migrations

I've previously been told that I should not put content on Pantheon in the development environment.

The reason was not explained.

Can anyone think of any reason that this should be advised?

I can see that pulling/pushing a lot of content form the /files directory could be and issue but is there any other reason that anyone can think of?

Comment: Are you sure it was put exactly like that? I'd imagine you've been advised that the proper direction for your DB workflow is Live -> Staging -> Testing, not the other way around. The reason should hopefully be obvious: content is added by users on the live site, and if you then overwrite that db with your dev db, where the new content doesn't exist, you'll wipe it out

Comment: In all honesty it was said to a colleague and not directly to me. I'm trying to clarify the logic behind the statement.

Thanks for your input Clive.

Comment: Gotcha...the phrase _"I should not put content on Pantheon in the development environment"_ is definitely incorrect in and of itself, that's why I asked. The person was probably referring to a live environment where multiple users edit content, and who _don't have access to the dev server site_. In such a case moving the database from Testing -> Staging -> Live would obviously be a big no-no as you'd overwrite changes - so content should go in on live only in that case. It's the same workflow recommended for Drush IIRC

Comment: Great. I'll go with that as a reason as I'm not entirely confident I can see another. It will not affect us as we will be hosting Live elsewhere. It will therefore just be test content whilst the site is in development.

Answer (score 1):

I think that either what you were told was not explained correctly, or that you misunderstood.

You can put content on development environments. And you should, to test.

But that content won't be migrated to production. If you want that content on production, you'll need to create it on production. Or, you can create a migration strategy (using the Migrate UI for example) to migrate content between environments. But this generally takes a good bit of work, and isn't usually done.